# Como instanciar WebHeaderCollection usando inicializadores de objeto?

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo uma requisição com o `WebClient` e gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar um Header dentro da instancia da classe `WebClient`, exemplo:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(){
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers =new WebHeaderCollection().Add("APIKey",API.APIKey) //Recebo erro aqui pois o retorno de `Add()` é void 
};
```

Sei que poderia resolver simplesmente fazendo assim:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient(){
            Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
 };
 client.Headers.Add("APIKey",API.APIKey);
```

Mas gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o que eu estava fazendo no primeiro código sem receber esse erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser feito assim:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient()
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection()
    {
        ["APIKey"] = "APIKey",
        ["APIKey1"] = "APIKey",
    }
};
```

[porque ele é um dicionário de dados e pode ser acessado dessa forma (*Ordered String/Object collection of name/value pairs with support for null key*)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/specialized/nameobjectcollectionbase.cs,4ade46c59f4e07b4).

- [Código NameObjectCollectionBase.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/specialized/nameobjectcollectionbase.cs,4ade46c59f4e07b4)

Importante também dizer que não precisa de uma nova instância, porque, `Headers` já está acessivel, então pode reduzir para esse código:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient()
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = 
    {
        ["APIKey"] = "APIKey",
        ["APIKey1"] = "APIKey",
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vai conseguir fazer desse jeito, porque não existe uma propriedade *public* na classe `WebHeaderCollection` que exponha a lista de valores para poder ser instanciada assim.

Veja a documentação: [WebHeaderCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection?view=netframework-4.7.2)

De uma maneira bem prática, ao abrir a `{` para contruir o objeto, não tem uma propriedade para poder construir o dicionário de headers, só é possível usando o método `Add`. Seria algo assim se fosse possível:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient
{
    Headers = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
    {
        { "APIKey",API.APIKey }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, é possível usar qualquer método `Add` que existe em `WebHeaderCollection` (o tipo da propriedade `Headers`).

Este é o método usado na inicialização de coleções.

Por exemplo:

Pode ser assim, separando a chave e o valor usando dois-pontos.

Usa o método [**`Add(string)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webheadercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebHeaderCollection_Add_System_String_)

```
var client = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection { $"APIKey: {API.APIKey}" }
};
```

Ou assim:

Usa o método [**`Add(NameValueCollection)`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_Add_System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_)

```
var client = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection 
    { 
        { "APIKey", API.APIKey } 
    }
}
```

Ou ainda, assim:

```
var client = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Headers = new WebHeaderCollection
    {
        ["APIKey"] = API.APIKey
    }
};
```